# Custom Drawing in UIControl Subclass Clipping

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

So, I'm doing some custom drawing in a `UIControl` subclass by overriding the `drawRect:` method. The issue is that the control is clipping a glow that I drew in it even though I've set the `clipsToBounds` property to `NO`.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the clipsToBounds property defines wether subviews will be clipped or not. Your view is still drawn in it's frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmeilioPelaez has it right. You can't draw outside your own frame. If you want the glow to overlap other UI elements, make the frame big enough to draw the glow, then make sure to set your own `opaque` flag to NO, and set the backgroundColor to `[UIColor clearColor]`. Keep in mind, compositing views incurs a pretty big performance hit, so maybe ask yourself if drawing that glow on top of other elements is really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My thinking was the product of a long day. Cheers!